# How to make this design using widgets in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

[image]

Please Help me to solve this question?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How far along have you gotten in creating this view? Share some code and the point where you are stuck and we will be happy to help.

Comment: A hint if you are stuck, you can use a Row widget, with three Columns, each of them being wrapped in Expanded to take equal space. You can center the children of the columns to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just your container take it:

```dart
Container(
          color: Color(0xffffe3b5),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("60+", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),), 
                    SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    Text("Cryptos", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("5k+", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),), 
                    SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    Text("Active users", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Text("100%", style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),), 
                    SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    Text("Positive Results", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),)
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

If you want to overlay widgets use the [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) widget